VueJS. Как избавиться от нативного форматирования строки Vue?
VueJS Понадобилось по-быстрому отформатировать список без написания самого списка, а с помощью <pre> элемента который сохраняет форматирование. Решил: нет ничего проще чем запихнуть <slot> в компонент между <pre> и после монтирования получить и разбить строки по \n:
<ul :class="styleType">
  <li v-for="(row, i) in list" :key="i">{{ row }}</li>
  <pre v-element-mnt>
    <slot></slot>
  </pre>
</ul>

... и использование в другом компоненте:
<UlList>
  Первое xyz
  Второе
</UlList>

Понятно: я ожидал увидеть список <ul>.
!!!Но, оказалось что Vue возвращает очищенную от \n строку:

А должна выглядеть так:

Есть ли способ избавиться от "очистки" и передать/получить в <slot> текст без форматирования?

v-html должен помочь в таких случаях. Если ну устраивает такой вариант, то можете поиграться со свойством white-space

@AzetX Я уже понял, что \n там ни к чему, по причине неудобства добавления длинных строк. И оптимальным оказалось использование обычной точки с запятой ; в качестве делителя. А при необходимости добавить к строке этот символ, можно добавить свойство делителя не по умолчанию к компоненту.
